# Is this broccoli crown safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, vegetables, broccoli

Was cutting up broccoli crowns and this bug appeared (I'm pretty sure it was from the crown). Is the broccoli still safe to eat? I checked every single piece I chopped up to make sure.

[image: bug]

Comment: If you knew how many insects and parts of insects were legally permitted to be in your food you may not worry too much about one bug that you actually removed. See here: http://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/SanitationTransportation/ucm056174.htm

Comment: You've got more bugs in the form of insect fragments in your spice cabinet than you have on your chopping board ;)

Comment: just a note, concernig broccoli and all vegetables, before you deal with them soak them for 15 minutes with water and vinegar, all insects and  bugs will be out of it, and it germinates it.

Comment: @Zeina - "Germinates it?"  What do you mean?  I associate that word with a seed sprouting from its formerly dormant state.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet excuse me i ment sterilizes it...

Comment: Soaking in water and vinegar in the proper ratio  will kill bacteria and clean vegetables and fruit, Sterilize might be a strong word.   i found this concerning sterilization  http://www.cooksinfo.com/peroxide-vinegar-sterilization         The bug is safe to eat, people eat bugs all over the world.

Comment: @Zeina - Okay.  No worries, just wondering if there was a use of the other term I wasn't familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily you caught it before it finished the whole crown :)

What you've got there is an [earwig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig) (probably one of the most creepy names possible for such a thing) and they're not known to be contaminants (they don't carry or transmit diseases to humans).

Hard to tell from the picture, but that one seems to either have just begun (or finished) a molting cycle - wash the broccoli well or (ideally) blanch it prior to eating.